# How do I minimize my taxes as an IT Employee in India?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, state-income-tax

I am working as java developer in start-up software company. My monthly salary is 30,000. The company takes my money as tax (1,500/month tax), and 2,000 for a food plus card. How do I get all of the money without paying tax? How many ways can I make deductions against the tax? I'm in Tamil Nadu India.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you have quoted don't add up. For Rs 30,000 / month is 3,60,000 a year. The tax should be around 11,000 again this will be reduced by the contributions to PF. You have indicated a tax deductions of 18,000.

There are multiple ways to save taxes. Since you are beginner, investments into section 80C should give you required tax benefits.

Please read this article in [Economic Times](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/tax/best-ways-to-save-tax-under-section-80c-of-the-income-tax-act/articleshow/50618606.cms)

Comment: list out the ways to save tax. it will help me?

Comment: what is 80C in india?